# I need to delete a commit to a fork

Tags: git, github

OK, I did something stupid.

- I forked a repo I am supposed to contribute to.
- So I then literally created a file called "blafile" to check I can commit (obviously I
  did not understand what a fork is) and committed with a message "check I can commit".
- I pushed to my github forked repo and forgot about it.
- I started fixing a bug on the next day.
- I committed my fix and pushed to my forked repo with message "fixed bug xyz".

Now I wanted to issue a pull request, and all of a sudden I see my "check I can commit" commit. I'd rather not like that to appear on the pull request. :)

Can I entirely delete that commit? Can I issue a pull request on a single commit or will it pull all my commits?

I know I can locally `git reset --hard HEAD~1`(it's a small fix I could redo quickly) but that only fixes my local repo, not my github (forked) repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lots of options.

The best option is probably to make a new branch and cherry-pick your fix into that branch:

```
git checkout -b my-fix-branch origin/master
git cherry-pick master
git push -u origin my-fix-branch
```

then do a pull request from `my-fix-branch` on GitHub. (This assumes your working branch is named `master`, based off the remote `master`; change the branch names as appropriate).

---

*IF* nobody has pulled or cloned your fork, you can rewrite history forcefully. Do `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and delete the offending commit, then `git push --force`. This will break any other repo based on your fork, so do *not* do this if you suspect anyone else is using your repo.

Comment: As I am sure nobody forked my repo (by looking at the fork graph), I rewrote history :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following sequence of commands should work assuming that your invalid commit was just one commit before the current HEAD, and the branch name is `master`.

**NOTE:** The following commands will be re-writing history which is not recommended if anyone has already cloned your repo. If that not be the case `push -f` should not be a big deal.

```
# Switch the current working tree to master branch
git checkout master
# Soft reset to get all the changes since HEAD~2 into the index/staging area
git reset --soft HEAD~2
# Remove the blafile from the staging area
git rm --cached blafile
# Commit the changes you actually intended to make
git commit
# Update the refs on the remote forcefully to push the newer commit.
# Note that if any one else has pulled master already with your blafile
# commit, they would be really pissed off with you now.
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: `push -f` is hazardous if anyone has pulled your repo.

Comment: @nneonneo - Yes, have added the comments indicating that. But from the looks of it, the OP wants to rewrite history, where there is no `blafile` at all without creating a new branch.